# In Java, what is the use case for new or enhancing the class loader?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

In Java, we know class loader is a JVM system which loads the classes into JVM for executiion. When I run a simple Java class , it is getting loaded and executed by the run time system. Here I am not doing anything with respect to the class loading. But I can see, there are various projects in which they are writing a custom class loader or enhancing the existing class loaders . Please let me know the production time use case where class loader enhancement or new class loader is required.

Answer (score 5):

The few   use case that I can think of right now:

1. You can use custom classloader to replace implementation during runtime (i.e without restarting server). It is being used heavily by JRebel
   https://www.jrebel.com/blog/how-to-reload-java-classes-at-runtime
2. Tomcat uses classloader to separate different webapps object scope at runtime.
   [How Tomcat Classloader separates different Webapps object scope in same JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559210/how-tomcat-classloader-separates-different-webapps-object-scope-in-same-jvm)
3. OSGI uses classloader to load bundles.
   [Java classloader usage in OSGi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737624/java-classloader-usage-in-osgi)

Comment: and more generally, fine control about what is loaded, when, how, etc.